# Ensuring Unique Fields when Randomly Generating MySQL rows

Tags: python, mysql, unique-constraint, mysql-python

I'm generating somewhere around 100,000 rows of random data, with around 10 columns, and I need to have all of values to be unique.

The only solid way I could think of doing this would be doing a query on each random generation to make sure that it does not exist yet, but that adds hundreds of thousands of queries. The other alternative would be creating a UNIQUE constraint on the table, but then I would need to have some way of counting how many duplicates fail, so that I can recreate those rows (I need to know that I will generate exactly as many random rows as specified), or having something that retries with a new generation when that insert fails. Is there a way to do that? Or am I missing some other approach all together?

Comment: how are you generating random values? Datatypes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should generate random numbers in python, in a list.
Then, use set to get uniques.

```
l = [1,5,5,4,5,4,8,9,2]

set(l)

set([1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9])
```

Now, you may generate 200.000 numbers to get at least 100.000 unique ones, and truncate the list, or so.

---

I tried this :

```
import random
l = []
for i in range (200000):
    l.append (random.random())
print len(set(l))
```

and it gave me a set of length 200.000. There were no dups within the generated random !

Comment: This seems like it may be the best solution. Needing to generate the extra numbers is a real pain, especially since I'd have to generate 2 x (number of cols) - or there abouts, which would be 2mil for 10 cols.

Answer (score 0):

What sorts of data are you filling the columns with? Does it have to follow any particular format?

Regardless of the data format, I'd generate all the data offline and then insert it into the DB all at once.

For example:

```
from base64 import b64encode
from random import shuffle

arr=[]
for i in range(0,1000000): #Assuming you need 1mil entries
    arr.append(b64encode(str(i)))
shuffle(arr)
#Add arr[] to the database
```

This way you know that all the strings will be unique, and the shuffle will make the order (more) random.